# Holoviews: how to update a plot with real time data?

Tags: real-time, holoviews

I am searching for an example that shows how to update a plot from live data.

Alas Holoviews examples/galleries don't show anything about this and I am stuck.

The only page I found is in Tutorial "Live Data" (http://holoviews.org/getting_started/Live_Data.html) but it plays with sliders instead of real data.

Can somebody point me to any source of info?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question I found looking for similar information. I believe using holoviews.streams.Pipe() with a holoviews.DynamicMap() is the answer:

See: http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Streaming_Data.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts here so that your answer does not lose its value when the linked page changes.